# Symfony2: call a route inside a command

Tags: symfony, controller, console, command, routes

I have a Command class from which I want to call a route to execute a controller.

```
MyClassCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected configure()
    {

    }

    protected execute()
    {

    }
}
```

How do I call a route from the method execute(), which will simply call an Action?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `$this->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('route_name', array('foo' => 'text'));`?

Comment: It does not work.

undefined method ::get(). Service is not exposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bundle can do this yet: [PhaxBundle](https://github.com/alcalyn/phax-bundle).

Declare your controller as a service, and simply call something like this in command:

```
$ php app/console phax:action yourcontroller youraction -p parametername:value
```

Comment: Then you can see how it does that in this file: https://github.com/alcalyn/phax-bundle/blob/master/Phax/CoreBundle/Command/ActionCommand.php

Comment: Ok. I have heard of that bundle (phax), but I thought this must be something simple which can be handled by Symfony2 core :)

Comment: Sure, you can also inspire you to the link I sent in comment, and simplify core calls

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code that you want to execute into an extra class, make it a service, then using it from both your controller and your command.

Then in your command class you can call your service like this :

`$this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('service');`

Comment: I have seen that you transform your controller into a service and then call it as though, here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

But it looks like the PHAX solution is the best regarding this issues :)